Apache CXF - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
I have migrated my application from Java 8 to Java 17 and upgrading corresponding dependent libraries, including javax to jakarta namespace refactor. However, I am facing issues with Apache CXF library trying to load javax.xml.bind library.
I am aware this was removed post Java 11, and I am trying to not include javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api in my pom.xml to avoid runtime issues.
This is the stack trace of the error I am getting:
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1353) ~[catalina.jar:?]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1165) ~[catalina.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3402) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:3427) ~[?:?]
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:2019) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.checkObjectFactoryNamespaces(JAXBContextCache.java:270) ~[cxf-core-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.common.jaxb.JAXBContextCache.getCachedContextAndSchemas(JAXBContextCache.java:182) ~[cxf-core-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.createJAXBContextAndSchemas(JAXBDataBinding.java:499) ~[cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxb.JAXBDataBinding.initialize(JAXBDataBinding.java:358) ~[cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.service.factory.AbstractServiceFactoryBean.initializeDataBindings(AbstractServiceFactoryBean.java:87) ~[cxf-core-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:469) ~[cxf-rt-wsdl-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.buildServiceFromClass(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:693) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.initializeServiceModel(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:529) ~[cxf-rt-wsdl-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.wsdl.service.factory.ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.create(ReflectionServiceFactoryBean.java:262) ~[cxf-rt-wsdl-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.support.JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.create(JaxWsServiceFactoryBean.java:199) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.createEndpoint(AbstractWSDLBasedEndpointFactory.java:103) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-simple-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientFactoryBean.create(ClientFactoryBean.java:91) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-simple-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxyFactoryBean.create(ClientProxyFactoryBean.java:158) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-simple-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]
    at org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.create(JaxWsProxyFactoryBean.java:142) ~[cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws-4.0.4.jar:4.0.4]


This is how my pom.xml looks like (I have already tried removing older ehcache and jaxb-runtime libaries which I thought might be causing the issue, but didn't help.
Ref: https://github.com/ehcache/ehcache3/issues/2946)
pom.xml:
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.4</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.ehcache</groupId>
<artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
<classifier>jakarta</classifier>
<version>3.10.8</version>
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.glassfish.jaxb</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-runtime</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.5</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.15.2</version>
</dependency>

Code:
<bean id="myJaxWsClient" class="com.package.SoapClient"
          factory-bean="soapClientFactory" factory-method="create"/>

<bean id="soapClientFactory"
          class="org.apache.cxf.jaxws.JaxWsProxyFactoryBean">
    <property name="serviceClass" value="com.package.SoapClient" />
    <property name="address" value="${EVENT_END_POINT}" />
</bean>


What makes you think that upgrading to Java 17 also requires moving from JavaEE to JakartaEE.

@M.Deinum Its not Java17, but couple of other reasons including upgrade to Tomcat 10 and Spring libraries

Then you need to upgrade CXF as well to a version that supports JakartaEE.

Did you use generated code from WSDL / XSD ? Did you update that too ? It seems some classes in your classpath is still using javax based JAXB, that would be a good starting point.
